# Table of a webpage is not grabbed when using readLines() in R, because it gets loaded after a few seconds

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** some data, stored in a table of a webpage that has observations.
I am using readLines() in order to get the page.

My problem is that, when checking the Lines grabbed, in the position that the table should be located at, there is a message: "No data recorded".

When loading this page in google chrome, this message "No data recorded" appears when the webpage is initially loaded. It stays for 3-4 seconds and then the message disappears and the table with the daily observations gets loaded.

So I guess that when using readLines(), the function does not "wait" to have the table loaded.

the url of the page is:

```
https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/gr/mykonos/LGMK/date/2017-11-1
```

and the codeline I type is:

```
thepage = readLines('https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/gr/mykonos/LGMK/date/2017-11-1')

thepage[695:700]
```

Comment: Sounds like the tables are loaded via javascript.  You'll need to use a tool that allows that javascript to run before extraction.

Comment: what kind of tool? do you have any to propose?